# TikZ Causal Graph Details (bold, arrow positions, text above paths)

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, graphs

I am having a hard time to figure out how to design a causal graph with TikZ. The graph should look like this:

[image: Causal graph]

The code below is as far as I get, but it does not have some important details (see picture). First, how do I add text on top of the paths (and in red)? I have seen examples using \draw where {text} suffices, but if I add that to my graph it does not compile anymore. Second, how can I add bold text and line breaks? Third, ideally, the arrows would start and stop before/after the nodes, as it is in the picture, and not at the center of the node (X to Z and Z to Y).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,calc,arrows.meta,fit,positioning}
\tikzset{
    -Latex,auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,
    state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.7 cm},
    point/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0.04cm,fill,node contents={}},
    bidirected/.style={Latex-Latex,dashed},
    el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left, sloped}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \node (1) at (6,0) {Some \ Text \ for \ X};
    \node (2) [right = 7cm of 1] {Some \ Text \ for \ Y};
    \node (3) [above right = 3cm of 1] {Some \ Text \ for \ Z};
    \node (t1) [above = 0.6cm of 3] {Text bold (with line break)};

    \draw (1) -- (2);
    \draw (3) -- (2) [anchor=west];
    \draw (1) -- (3);
    
    \node (4) at (6,6) {Some \ Text \ for \ X};
    \node (5) [right = 7cm of 4] {Some \ Text \ for \ Y};
    \node (6) [above right = 3cm of 4] {Some \ Text \ for \ Z};
    \node (t2) [above = 0.6cm of 6] {Text bold (with line break)};


    \draw (4) --  (5);
    \draw (6) -- (5);
    \draw (4) -- (6);
    
    
    \node (7) at (6,12) {Some \ Text \ for \ X};
    \node (8) [right = 7cm of 7] {Some \ Text \ for \ Y};
    \node (9) [above right = 3cm of 7] {Some \ Text \ for \ Z};
    \node (t2) [above = 0.6cm of 9] {Text bold (with line break)};


    \draw (7) --  (8);
    \draw (9) -- (8);
    \draw (7) -- (9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see:

- to have multiline nodes, you have to specify an `align` key; to have automatic line breaks, you need a `text width`
- to change the font of the node you can use the key `font`
- to add text around path, you can just put `node` in the middle of the path. By default it is horizontal and in the middle, but you can change that with `sloped` and `pos` keys.

Example (this is minimal, and do not have nested `tikzpicture`...)

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,calc,arrows.meta,fit,positioning}
\tikzset{
    -Latex,auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,
    state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.7 cm},
    point/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0.04cm,fill,node contents={}},
    bidirected/.style={Latex-Latex,dashed},
    el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left, sloped}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (1) at (6,0) {Some \ Text \ for \ X};
    \node (2) [right = 7cm of 1] {Some \ Text \ for \ Y};
    \node (3) [above right = 3cm of 1] {Some \ Text \ for \ Z};
    \node (t1) [above = 0.6cm of 3, text width=4cm, align=center, font=\bfseries] {Text bold (with line break)};
    \draw (1) -- node[red, above ]{text in red} (2);
    \draw (3) -- node [red, above , sloped] {text in red, sloped} (2) [anchor=west];
    \draw (1) -- node [red, above left, pos=0.2, align=center] {text in red,\\ horizontal at 0.2} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of the above snippet]

Then there are several libraries to simplify the input of such kinds of diagrams; one nice starting point is [the second tutorial in the Ti*k*Z manual](https://tikz.dev/tutorial-nodes).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

As commutative diagram:

```
\documentclass[border?3.141592]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
arrow style = tikz,
     arrows = {>=Straight Barb, semithick},
     % nodes = {align=center}
            }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}%[ampersand replacement=\&]
   &   \textbf{\makecell{Text bold\\ (with line break)}}
        &   \\
   &   \text{Some Text for Z}  \ar[rd, "\beta"]
        &   \\
\text{Some Text   for X}   \ar[ur, "\alpha"] \ar[rr, "\gamma" ']
    &   &   \text{Some Text for Y}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]